# Select 1 as one - Ruby Queries rolls back in staging and prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to update the quantity of the products table after the payment has succeeded on my rails app.
This is how I am doing it,

```
@orders1 = Order.where("shoppingcart_id" => @cart.id)
@orders1.each do |order|
@oproduct = Product.where("id" => order.product.id).first
  if(@oproduct.quantity >=1 )
    @oproduct.quantity = @oproduct.quantity - 1;
    @oproduct.save
  end
end
```

When I am looking into the query logs, I see Ruby runs this select 1 as one query -

```
Product Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE 
"products"."name" = ? AND "products"."id" != ? LIMIT ?
```

On my local (SQLLite), it works fine without any rollbacks and my product quantity gets updated correctly. 
But when I run the same on staging, it fails. The transaction rolls back.
On one other local machine, it fails as well. I am not able to reproduce this on my local and not sure why this is happening either. The other updates are working perfectly fine, like orders update. Only the product quantity update fails.

Is that product exists query mandatory? Not sure if I am missing any setting for my staging or is there any problem with the code.

Comment: Can you please show the validations that are present in `product.rb`

Comment: You can use @oproduct.save! to know if there are any ActiveRecord errors.

Comment: @NimishGupta here it is   validates :name, :description, :price,:picture,:quantity, presence: true 
   validates :seo_title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 75}, on: :create
    validates :seo_description, presence: true, length: {maximum: 120}, on: :create
   belongs_to :shop
   belongs_to :category
   has_many :orders
       validates_uniqueness_of :name

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`@product = Product.find(order.product.id)
  if @product.quantity > 0
    @product.update_attributes!(quantity: @product.quantity -1)
  end`